# Fatal error: Call to undefined function svn_auth_set_parameter() svn PHP

Tags: php, windows, svn, dll

hi i am trying to connect `svn` from windows 64bit. i got this error  `Call to undefined function svn_auth_set_parameter()`

i searched the internet and through the guidance of

http://www.php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php

i downloded and placed `php_svn.dll` inside `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folders.
and also i download and placed

intl3_svn.dll, libdb43.dll, libapr.dll, libapriconv.dll, libaprutil.dll, libeay32.dll, msjava.dll, php5ts.dll, ssleay32.dll, vsinit.dll, msvcr71.dll, MSVCP71.DLL

files inside `C:\Windows\System32` folder . but the error remains .

i tried to run `regsvr32 php_svn.dll` but it also gives an error .

am i missing something here , also i restarted windows few times .

please help . thanks in advance .

Comment: did you include that library in your php.ini as an extension?

Comment: Look into the PHP documentation pages and into your php.ini files. That is actually your job... (sorry if i sound rude)

Comment: it is ok :) , i forogot , i have already added php_svn.dll to "C:\xampp\php\ext" , it is the place defined in php.ini -> extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext" , ut not working :(

Comment: did you explicitly set the extension itself? not only the directory. php won't load any extension from a directory unless you tell it to load it!

Comment: something in the manner of `extension=php_svn.dll`

Comment: @ITroubs , ah .... missed that one , i ll give it a try . thanks :)